# Retrieving Azure Tenant ID, Client ID and Client Secret Securely for GitLab Pipeline

Tags: azure, gitlab, terraform, azure-keyvault, hashicorp-vault

I am setting up a GitLab pipeline to run some Terraform configuration to enable OIDC authentication between our Azure AD and HashiCorp Vault instances. A proof of concept of this solution has been successfully implemented.

To protect some of the sensitive data consumed, there is a requirement to store the following Azure credentials securely, encrypted and injected into the GitLab pipeline when run:

1. Tenant ID
2. Client ID
3. Client Secret

We'd therefore like to identify and implement an ideal solution to achieve this objective and will readily consider secure storage options using AWS, Azure or HashiCorp Vault which are all part of our tech stack. Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The Tenant ID and Client ID are not particularly sensitive information, so I don't think you need to necessarily store/access these securely.

To protect the client secret, you can use group variables.

Saving the secrets to services like Azure Key Vault would be possible, but you'd need an application registration (another client id and secret) to retrieve it again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO Julian. I've edited your answer to be a bit more direct and fit better as an answer, rather than a suggestion or clarifying question. Once you have enough reputation, you'll be able to comment on questions to ask clarifying details.

Answer (score 0):

That's the thing with secrets: You have to start somewhere. That problem is often called "secure introduction". Let's follow that trail.

It starts with registering Vault in Azure-AD, giving you back the values you are concerned with. If you register Vault in Azure-AD in your pipeline, the best is to hold on to the values and reuse them right away to configure Vault's OIDC auth backend.

But based on your requirements, you can't store them in your Terraform state. There is also the problem of changing the client secret on a regular basis, say every year or so.

When you register Vault in Azure-AD, write the credentials in a version 2 KV store, with restricted policies. Even though only the client secret is a secret, we store the credentials in a document like this:

```
{
   "client_id": "..........",
   "client_secret": "...........",
   "tenant_id": "............"
}
```

We then read these values from Vault, and use them to configure the OIDC auth backend. When the client secret change, there are put as a new version of the secret and are picked up by the next run of the configuration pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

OIDC does not require storing or accessing the client secret in GitLab. That's the primary benefit of using OIDC: you do not have to store/access any secrets in GitLab. You just use the `$CI_JOB_JWT_V2` token.

This is not a direct answer to your question about securely accessing credentials, which has been answered by other answers. But I will show you how to setup OIDC such that you don't even have to store client secret in the first place.

---

First, you will need to register an Application in Azure. You can do this by following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) to register an application and create a service principal.

After doing this, make note of the values for **Application (client) ID** and **Directory (tenant) ID** (found in the application Overview pane). These values will be needed for step 3.

Second, you will need to add the federated credentials to the application's service principal. In the Azure portal, go to **registered apps** -> **your application**. In the sidebar, select **Certificates & secrets**. Under the **Federated credentials** tab, click the "Add credential" button

Use the following parameters for the credential configuration:

**Federated credential sceanrio**: *Other issuer*
**Issuer**: your gitlab URL e.g. `https://gitlab.example.com`
**Subject Identifier**: The value of the `sub` claim to match. For example, to allow jobs on the `main` branch of the `contoso/myproject` project to use this service principal, use `project_path:contoso/myproject:ref_type:branch:ref:main`
**Name**: Any descriptive name for the federated credental (e.g. `contoso-myproject-main`)
**Description**: Optional, a description for the federated credential.
**Audience**: your GitLab URL e.g. `https://gitlab.example.com`

Finally, you can now use OIDC to login to Azure from gitlab:

```yaml
azure-cli:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  variables:
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: "YOUR Application Client ID"
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: "YOUR TENANT ID"
  script:
    - az login --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --federation-token $CI_JOB_JWT_V2
    # now you are logged into Azure and can take other actions using the CLI
    # - az resource list # example
```

Note the client ID and tenant ID are not sensitive pieces of information, so they can reasonably be added directly to your YAML.

Comment: sytech, apologies but perhaps I didn't really explain my issue very well..........or perhaps I've completely misunderstood the solution you're proposing. Let me however clarify/reiterate a few points. Firstly, as stated previously, a proof of concept to test the solution already works perfectly outside of GitLab, where I set hardcoded values in my terraform configuration for all three Azure credentials.

Comment: The requirement is to use a GitLab pipeline to execute my Terraform configuration and in doing so, we cannot have hardcoded values stored for those three credentials. Ideally, we want them stored securely somewhere (HashiCorp Vault, Azure KeyVault, etc) and then inject them into the pipeline when it's triggered.

Comment: Will this approach you're proposing therefore still work in this scenario?

Comment: Yes. You can also use the same token for connecting to vault if needed.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the azure-cli code snippet you suggested above, will be included in my .gitlab-ci.yml CI/CD pipeline script? Also, are you able to provide an example of how you'd set the two variables (AZURE_CLIENT_ID & AZURE_TENANT_ID) in the yml file, ensuring they're masked or hidden?

Comment: The client ID and tenant ID are not sensitive values, but you can set them as masked variables in the project settings if you really want to.